# Can't remove object via python once grouped

Tags: python, objects, groups

I'm writing a script that is adding and removing about 50 objects every frame. That part is working fine, but once I add the objects to a group, it creates odd errors.

In tracking down the error, I simplified my project and ran into the same issue

I could understand if the group were one of the users of the object, but the object.users count doesn't increase when grouped.

Try it yourself:

```
import bpy

scn = bpy.data.scenes['Scene']
ob = bpy.data.objects['Cube']

scn.objects.unlink(ob)
bpy.data.objects.remove(ob)
```

works fine, but:

```
import bpy

scn = bpy.data.scenes['Scene']
ob = bpy.data.objects['Cube']

testgroup = bpy.data.groups.new('testgroup')
testgroup.objects.link(ob)
testgroup.objects.unlink(ob)

scn.objects.unlink(ob)
bpy.data.objects.remove(ob)
```

throws the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Error: Object 'Cube' must have zero users to be removed, found 1
```

What's going on? Am I missing something, or do I need to file a bug report?

Comment: yes it could be a bug, tested after adding `user_clear()` and got the same result, please add your blender version ( mine is 2.77 a )

Comment: Same, I'm on 2.77a

Comment: try it on older version if you have one or wait for some to do  ( to make sure it's )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I submitted a bug report, and got a same day response from Bastien. Turns out, the problem is related to the Fake User restructuring that is going on and there isn't a straightforward way to do it. Here's a link to the bug report: [Blender Bug Tracker](https://developer.blender.org/T48360)

He also pointed me in the direction of an effective workaround that I thought I'd share. Here is the working code:

```
import bpy

scn = bpy.data.scenes['Scene']
ob = bpy.data.objects['Cube']

testgroup = bpy.data.groups.new('testgroup')
testgroup.objects.link(ob)
testgroup.objects.unlink(ob)

scn.objects.unlink(ob)

ob.user_clear()    #manually clears all users, frees the object to be removed

bpy.data.objects.remove(ob)
```

Comment: I have tried that see my comment and got the same error

Comment: This results in the following error: 

`AttributeError: 'bpy_prop_collection' object has no attribute 'objects'`

Answer (score 1):

No you don't appear to be missing anything. I just tested it here with versions from 2.70 to 2.76 and they do not show this error, so it is a regression introduced in 2.77.

You should report it [as a bug at developer.blender.org](https://developer.blender.org/maniphest/task/create/?project=2&type=Bug)